# Variable as key in array

Tags: php, arrays

Why can't I use variable as key in array?

```
class example{
    protected $name = 'test';
    protected $routingArray = [
        'get' => [
            '/' => 'homeAction',
            '/kontakt' => 'contactAction',
            $this->name => 'exampleAction'
         ]
    ];
}
```

In the line with `$this->name` I get error "unexpected variable". What's wrong? Why can't I use it like that? How can I do it maybe another way to get the same result?

Comment: Why would you want to?

Comment: @DainisAbols I need this key to be dependent on other variable

Comment: Are you able to show us more of the context that necessitates this?

Comment: @Olga are u correctly defining the variable before using it ? Can you show us the whole code

Comment: are you sure your $name is a string?

Comment: @olibiaz  I updated my question with actual code, wchich doesn't work for sure

Comment: $this->name is not accessible before construct, please instanciate $routingArray in the class constructor

Comment: There is no `$this` there yet, and even if there was, variables aren't supported at that point. Since `$name` is pre-defined anyway, there's really no difference in just using `'test'` instead of `$this->name`.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to define a wildcard route. Are you using a web framework for this?